# Variable and its dynamics in one multiple regression model

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

I am trying to find the dependence between default rates in bank and macroeconomic variables with linear regression.
To do so I created a code which estimates every possible model - every combination of variables is tested. As an output I obtain R-squared, statistics for Chow, Breusch-Pagan, Breusch-Godfrey, RESET and Shapiro-Wilk tests as well as VIF.
The only model which pass all tests, has satisfying R-squared and low VIF is as follows:
$ y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_t + \beta_2 \varDelta x_t$
where $ \varDelta x_t = x_t - x_{t-1} $. Altough using variable and its dynamics in one model seems a bit strange, I did not find any reason to reject the model. I would be grateful if someone could help me motivate accepting or rejecting such a model.

Comment: It would be better to ask this question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Aleksander Gorczański if you do migrate it to stats, could you please share the link so I can read the answers as well? Thank you

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Here is the link https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/427633/variable-and-its-dynamics-in-one-multiple-regression-model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plugging-in $\Delta x_t$ into the model, you have
$$
y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_t + \beta_2x_t - \beta_2x_{t-1} + \epsilon_t,
$$
denote $\theta_1 = \beta_1 + \beta_2$ and $-\beta_2 = \theta_2$ your model is
$$
y_t = \beta_0 + \theta_1 x_t + \theta_2 x_{t-1} + \epsilon_t.
$$
Which, from statistical point of view has nothing extraordinary. I.e., the expected value of $Y$ (rate?) at time $t$ given the history of the process $X_t$ up to time $t$ depends only on its current ($t$) and previous ($t-1$) values. Whether it make-sense from an economical point of view - is a matter of economic theory, not statistics.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it is clear!